# Scala's .map() function on a immutable and mutable maps

Tags: scala, immutability, mutable

When calling `.map()` on a map of a large length, which will be faster

1. Calling it on a mutable map
2. Calling it on a immutable map
3. Or it will not make a difference

Comment: Why don't you just measure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's just check it (of course, microbenchmark results should always be taken with a grain of salt).

Using [Scalameter](http://scalameter.github.io/):

```
// build.sbt

scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.storm-enroute" %% "scalameter" % "0.6"
)

// src/main/scala/main.scala

import org.scalameter.api._
import scala.collection.immutable
import scala.collection.mutable

object RangeBenchmark extends PerformanceTest.Quickbenchmark {
  val sizes = Gen.range("size")(100000, 500000, 100000)

  val immutableMaps = for {
    size <- sizes
  } yield immutable.Map((0 until size).map(n => n -> (size-n)).toSeq: _*)

  val mutableMaps = for {
    size <- sizes
  } yield mutable.Map((0 until size).map(n => n -> (size-n)).toSeq: _*)

  performance of "immutable.Map" in {
    measure method "map" in {
      using(immutableMaps) in { m => m.map { case (k, v) => (k+1, v+1) } }
    }
  }

  performance of "mutable.Map" in {
    measure method "map" in {
      using(mutableMaps) in { m => m.map { case (k, v) => (k+1, v+1) } }
    }
  }
}
```

Running (`sbt run`):

```
... lots of output ...

::Benchmark immutable.Map.map::
cores: 4
jvm-name: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
jvm-vendor: Oracle Corporation
jvm-version: 24.65-b04
os-arch: amd64
os-name: Linux
Parameters(size -> 100000): 40.95331
Parameters(size -> 200000): 90.12223
Parameters(size -> 300000): 139.716564
Parameters(size -> 400000): 208.114459
Parameters(size -> 500000): 254.876849

... lots of output ...

::Benchmark mutable.Map.map::
cores: 4
jvm-name: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
jvm-vendor: Oracle Corporation
jvm-version: 24.65-b04
os-arch: amd64
os-name: Linux
Parameters(size -> 100000): 24.004582
Parameters(size -> 200000): 52.941946
Parameters(size -> 300000): 66.036803
Parameters(size -> 400000): 113.575799
Parameters(size -> 500000): 119.544183
```

Apparently, mutable map is almost exactly two times faster. My guess is that this happens because of a difference in map `Builder`s: immutable map builder is a `var` which is updated with each added element, while mutable map builder is the mutable map itself. Consequently, with large map sizes, immutable map builder causes more allocations. This is really a wild guess, so maybe someone more knowledgeable would give the correct reason.